# Find item index with lambda or linkq in c#

Tags: c#, list, lambda, generic-list, generic-lambda

Hi i can't speak english well forgive me if ill confuse you.

in c# i have  3 **String** List.

list_one: list of file address.

list_two: list of MD5 that makes with *list_one*.

list_three: list of MD5 that makes with *list_two* but in this list i collect duplicate item from *list_two*

**Question** :

How can i get each item in list_three and search that in list_two then  return that index.

but i dont like to use for or foreach because that will slow my application.

how can do that with linq or lambda or any fastest way.

[my lists Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyyTk.png)

Comment: for or foreach isn't slower than linq and perfectly fine for the homework

Comment: @VladL i need do this for 11000 item.do you have any idea?

Comment: "but i dont like to use for or foreach because that will slow my application." This statement seems to stem from a gross misunderstanding of something.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your existing code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  A [mcve] showing the code you have so far and where you are stuck would be ideal, and maximize your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No 1 `foeach` isn't slower. But to answer what you want is simple one liner like this.

```
using System.Linq;  

List<string> list = new List<string>{"a","b","c","d"};
List<string> list2 = new List<string>{"a","c"};  

var result = list.Select((a, b) => new {Value = a, Index = b})
              .Where(x => list2.Any(d => d == x.Value))
              .Select(c => c.Index).ToArray();
```

now `result` contains all the match indexes.[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/5FkRSx)

Comment: tnx for your answer but its not work

Comment: it does work . Check i've updated

Comment: does not work again

Comment: @rezaparsian check !

Comment: its work we forgot to use **ToList()** but the answer is false. but i think i got that how its work

Comment: The answer is not false ! how the answer is false ? and if it helped you accept as answer Thanks

Comment: its return duplicate index.its search for *Rao* find it in index 0 but we have anothere *Rao* in index 10 but its return 0 again

Comment: @rezaparsian i've updated my answer and now your issue is resolved. Please check

Comment: tnx♥ now can u help me to pass this list to my first list and return value?